# angular adding a tag hyperlink dinamically with additional parameters

Tags: html, angular, hyperlink

I have some string variable in angular to which I assign html and then put it to the template

```
varString = "<a [routerLink]="[]" class="some class" >test</a>"
```

and then assign template div with this variable.
This creates hyperlink tag with class "some class"
But now I want to add some additional parameteres to it, for example id.

```
varString = "<a [routerLink]="[]" class="some class" id="123">test</a>"
```

like this.But unfortunately it generates the same hyperlink without additional parameters.
I've tried different ways but no additional parameters are added to a tag. Is this because of angular ? if I write it directly in template html page everything is fine.

This is stackblitz link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xhpoxe
Please inspect element after creation and you can see it takes only class parameter

Comment: Could you provide stackblitz please

Comment: added stackblitz link. Please inspect element after creation to check whats inside 'a' tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happed because angular sanitize your string by itself for [content security](https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-and-security-contexts) reasons. You need to use [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) and say angular your content is safe.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xyifdu)